# Highlight linked elements when clicked as in "focus"

Tags: css

I've been looking for ages with no luck. Our e-commerce site has application links in a lookup table to a detail table containing info & shopping cart buttons. In browsers where it works, "focus" sort of does the job (on the anchor cell at least), but I need ideas on how to have the entire link target row change background color or text color. The site is www.maxrules.com, an outboard motor parts supplier. "http://maxrules.com/fixomcsealkit.html" is one page with the basic idea. Click one of the part number links to the detail chart. I need the target line to somehow differ from the rest so customers are sure to get the right one. This probably involves js as well but not sure which forum to post in. This seem more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

CSS has the `:target` selector for this

```
:target { color: red;}
```

It's however not supported by IE 6-8. For it to work on IE you need JS. Something like

```
<a href="#name" onclick="document.getElementById(this.href.substr(1)).className='target';">
```

than in CSS use

```
.target {color: red;}
```

Only downside is that this script doesn't remove the class if some other link is clicked, so you can end up with multiple products with red color. Can be fixed with some more JS, but I leave to up to you

PS. in case of the maxrules site, you don't need the empty `<a>` elements, you can just add `id="1212"` to the `<tr>` element. This also fixes that currently the top part of the part is clipped, when clicking on a link.